# How to make certain area transparent in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, patterns

I have a rectangle with a grid pattern as fill:

[image]

Now I want the white part to be transparent so I can add a background image to it. I didn't find a way to do it. I know if you are in Photoshop you can use the quick selection tool but I am in Illustrator. So how do you do it in Illustrator? Thanks

Comment: You would probably have to edit the pattern fill itself to have no background

Answer (score 1):

Ok, try this.

1. Select your rectangle.
2. Go `Object > Expand Appearance`.
3. Now select one background 'tile' from the rectangle's background and go `Select > Same > Fill & Stroke` to select all of the background tiles.
4. Hit <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Alternatively, use one of Illustrator's built-in grid pattern swatches, which have no background colour. In the **Swatches panel**, click the drop-down and go `Open Swatch Library > Patterns > Basic Graphics` and you'll find a whole heap of grids. Or, create your own pattern tile and convert that into a pattern swatch (simply make something, group it and drag it into the Swatches panel).

Answer (score 1):

1. Drag your pattern out of the swatch panel
2. Make white invisible (for some patterns this means you may need to make a new bounding box.)
3. Drag the pattern back to the swatch panel.

   - Either <kbd>alt</kbd> drag and overwrite the old pattern.
   - Or make a new pattern and reapply.

[image]

**Image 1**: Timelapse of the process

Some closing thoughts. I wouldn't use a pattern for a grid there are several reasons for this but simply put it's not very efficient. In any case it should  take no time to recreate the pattern form scratch.

Answer (score -2):

Please do the following Step:

1. Select the rectangle
2. Go to `Object > Rasterize`
3. Set Background to `Transparent` (see below)
   [image]
4. Keep the rectangle selected and go `Image Trace > Line Art` 
   [image]
5. You are done :)

Comment: This is a extremely bad workflow. This is also a bad advice because it kind of works, albeit badly, making somebody a actually use it.

Comment: Then why you are not give the solution? prove it.

Comment: Dear god, drag the pattern form you swatch panel to your document. make the white parts invisible and drag it back to the swatch panel. Done, and you have saved a ton of time and effort, and memory and hard disk and your pattern is now clean.

Comment: not working it for me